# Does updating a file in the server change its gzip version?

Tags: php, gzip

I have a website with some files that I'm serving using gzip compression. I'm concerned that if I update the file, the gzip version may not be updated and users may not see the latest changes.

Does updating a file change its gzip version? Or do I need to manually update the gzip version of the file after making changes to it? How long does it take for the gzip version to be updated after the original file has been modified?

I want to ensure that my users always see the latest version of my files and I'm looking for guidance on how to best manage the gzip versions of my files.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by: _"gzip version of a file"_?

Comment: When I activate zlib.output_compression in the php.ini, the system creates a gzip version of my files, right? That's what I mean. Sorry if I'm wrong. I'm struggling to understand how it workss. I have read a lot about it, but it's not clear yet in my head.

Comment: OK, well, I'm not an expert, but this is how I believe it works: The client requests a file from the server, indicating which encoding it can process with a header. For instance: `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br`. The server picks up on the `gzip` in there and gzips the file it sends. The client then ungzips it before it presents it to the user. So, the whole compression thing is transparent from the user's point of view. The compression and decompression is done on the fly.

Comment: On the fly??? So I was totally wrong about that. Things start to make sense now. Thanks a lot, man. I think I need to study more, but it's not easy when you have a website showing errors everywhere to fix. Again, thank you!

Comment: No problem, I also often find that basic stuff is poorly documented. We all have to learn these things somehow.

Comment: Just a last question, if you don't mind. I've found a strange gzipped folder in my public folder (it seems it had been created automatically). And that's what led me to think that files were compressed in advance and placed in a folder to be served later on. What could be the purpose of that folder?

Comment: I have no idea. It's probably unrelated to the gzipping that is done for file transport between the server and the browser.